# upload a txt file and save into database

Tags: c#, .net, database, string, winforms

I have to make a c# program that will read text files and extract the data needed and create a database. A text file would be like the example below, this is just one category Country results, after the Country the is district results and for each district there are all the Election locations. All of that in the same text file. How can i read a large text file like that and the program can understand if its country,district or location, go take all the values, as well as the names with their values and store it in a corresponding database? I am new , i have written some code , but it reads line by line.Thus if 1 line is added in the file the program wont be able to read it correctly.

For now i have tried to just find a way to extract the data i need. This is not exactly how the file is since i cant include real data and its in greek also. But you get the idea, now i just read line by line. But the txt file must always be exacltly the same way written with this way in order to get the data correclty. Since i am really new in programming like 2 months this is a really hard task :)

```
COUNTRY RESULTS
ON A TOTAL: 545,491 REGISTERED VOTES (PARTICIPATION = 100,00%)
FROM: 1,138 ELECTION CENTERS (PARTICIPATION = 100,00%)
LOST: 0 CENTERS WITH 0 REGISTERED VOTES
STAY: 91.957 16.86%
VOTED: 453,534 (447,489 + 6,045) 83,14%
NOK: 7.819 1.72%
WHITE: 4.459 0.98%
QUARTERLY: 441.256 97.29%
WRITTEN WITHOUT WARRANTIES: 161
NAME VOTES PERCENTAGE
BOB TAYLOR 1.278 0.29% N / A
MARIA MARIA 213 0,05% T / S
GEORGE GEO 109.996 24.93% T / A
JOHN SOLLA 118.755 26.91% T / S
LISA TERRA 1.898 0.43% T / S


DISTRICT RESULTS
ON A TOTAL: 545,491 REGISTERED VOTES (PARTICIPATION = 100,00%)
FROM: 1,138 ELECTION CENTERS (PARTICIPATION = 100,00%)
LOST: 0 CENTERS WITH 0 REGISTERED VOTES
STAY: 91.957 16.86%
VOTED: 453,534 (447,489 + 6,045) 83,14%


private void insrtBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String line;
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line !=null)
            {
                //write the lie to console window
                MessageBox.Show(line);


                string firstWord = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" "));//Read first word of string
                line = sr.ReadLine();//Read the next line
                switch (firstWord)
                {
                    case "COUNTRY":
                        if(line.StartsWith("ON"))
                        {


                            getOneNumber(line);

                          line = sr.ReadLine();



                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("FROM:"))
                        {

                            getOneNumber(line);
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("LOST:"))
                        {

                            line = sr.ReadLine();
                        }

                        if (line.StartsWith("STAY:"))
                        {

                            getTwoNumbers(line);
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("VOTED:"))
                        {
                            string str = line;
                            str = (str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf(":") + 1)).Trim();
                            string str1 = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(" ")).Trim();
                            string str2 = (str.Replace(str1, " ")).Trim();
                            str2 = (str2.Remove(0,str2.IndexOf("\t"))).Trim();
                            MessageBox.Show(str1);

                            line = sr.ReadLine();
                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("NOK:"))
                        {

                            getTwoNumbers(line);
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("WHITE:"))
                        {

                            getTwoNumbers(line);
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("QUARTERLY:"))
                        {

                            getTwoNumbers(line);
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("WRITTEN"))
                        {

                            string str = line;
                            str = (str.Remove(0, str.IndexOf(":")+1)).Trim();
                        //    str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("")).Trim();
                            MessageBox.Show(str);
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        }
                        if (line.StartsWith("NAME VOTES"))
                        {

                            line = sr.ReadLine();
                        }

                        while (line != "")

                        {
                            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ':', '\t' };

                            string text = line;
                            string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);


                            foreach (string s in words)
                            { 

                                MessageBox.Show(s);
                            }

                            line = sr.ReadLine();


                        }
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                        line = sr.ReadLine();



                        break;
```

Comment: Please include [mcve] code to help anyone reproduce the problem (even it doesn't fit your need or not working).

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: "in a corresponding database" - before you write code, you should decide what your database (table(s)) will look like. Because if you don't care about _how_ the data is stored, you might as well store the entire file as a single value in the database.